# bash if statement behaviour question

Tags: bash, shell-script

I wrote this following piece of bash script.

```
if [ $(tmux has -t junk) ]
then
echo zero
else
echo one
fi
```

It always returns one, no matter if the session exists or not. I checked in the command line by executing the tmux statement and then running $? . It behaves as expected, zero if session exists and one if session does not exists Why isn't if statement is not behaving the same way. I tried changing the if statement like below

```
tmux has -t junk
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo zero
else
echo one
fi
```

The above thing works. So whats wrong with the first statement block ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned `if [ $(tmux has -t junk) ]` expand to to `if [ ]` which evaluates to false.

You could use:

```
if tmux has -t junk; then
    echo OK
else
    echo ERR
fi
```

Or if you want the shorter:

```
tmux has -t junk || echo ERR
```

Or

```
tmux has -t junk && echo OK || echo ERR
```

You can also negate it if that is more suitable, as in:

```
! tmux has -t junk || echo OK
! tmux has -t junk && echo ERR || echo OK
etc.
```

---

Edit:

Also not that if a command produces output you might want to redirect that 
output to the black hole of `/dev/null` as in:

```
 if my_cmd >/dev/null; then echo OK else; echo ERR; fi
```

If the command produces textual error you'd might want to redirect standard 
error as well by:

```
 if my_cmd >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo OK else; echo ERR; fi
```

---

This, what follows, you might already know well, but add it for a bit more 
completeness.

As mentioned: `$?` is the only way to get the return value of the program.

Some programs vary return and can have a rather explicit meaning.

So e.g.:

```
mycmd
ecode=$?

case "$ecode" in
0) echo "Success";;
1) echo "Operation not permitted";;
2) echo "No such file or directory";;
esac
```

By this one can take appropriate action on specific errors.

If you have MySQL installed you can do e.g. this by [perror](http://linux.die.net/man/1/perror):

```
for i in {0..50}; do perror $i; done
# And
for i in {1000..1050}; do perror $i; done
```

to get a feel for it.

See also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8362/28489) related to OS specific errors which also links to Open Groups doc [Error Numbers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_03.html) and [errno.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/errno.h.html).

Or take a look at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html) and its [extended ones](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort_rollback.html).

Comment: Wow if tmux ... works! thanks. I understand if [ `cmd` ] expands to output of cmd. How if cmd work ?

Comment: @ashwin: Not sure I get what you ask. But if `cmd` has any output that would result in test being performed on that output. `[` is a command with `]` as last parameter. In turn that would most probably result in an error depending on output. Say the `cmd` prints `*Blah blah\n some info\n more blah*` all of that would be the test expression. You might want to look at the answers [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71246/28489).

Comment: @ashwin: Note e.g. comment on [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56655/what-is-the-difference-between-a-z-and-a-z/56674#56674) on the `[` test command.

Answer (score 1):

When you use:

```
if [ $(tmux has -t junk) ]
```

This checks the output of the command `tmux has -t junk` but not the return value.

So since it is always printing one as in the first case, this means that `tmux has -t junk` command is not printing anything on the standard output.

So in first case,

```
if [ $(tmux has -t junk) ]
```

is getting evalauted as

```
if [ ]
```

Comment: How to check for return value ? Is $? the only way ?

Comment: Yes, `$?` is the only way to find out the return value.